# Asp.net MVC: Edit html control for Admin

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a Asp.net MVC web application, containing mostly text. I want to put a feature into it so that admin can easily edit text/html using the web. May be some double clicking on a page and converting it into editable and save able. How can i do it? any sample code?

I need this to be done for Asp.net MVC.

Comment: can you please provide more information on what you need to do? do you want to edit a list of products for an online-shop? I suggest you write a separate controller for that, so separate pages will be used.

Comment: There are just 5-6 pages each containing 10-15 paragraphs. I just want to edit n save those (only Admin). There are many jQuery based Edit in Place plug ins are available but not sure how to save data permanently on pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [jQuery Edit in Place](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) plugin.

- Make sure you have a database table with a row for each paragraph (could also be an XML file or some other means of storing structured data)
- When rendering your pages, make each `<p>` has a class 'editable'
- When the user requesting the page is an admin, do a

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('p.editable').editable(...); 
  });
- When the admin edits text, submit it to an action like this:

  public JSONResult Edit(int id, string content){
    /* Update content */
    /* Return new text from database (in case something went wrong, the data won't have changed - you could return a JSON datastructure signaling an error */
    return Json(newcontent);
  }
- Insert the new content in the paragraph.

Comment: If you are using the jEditable plugin I linked to above, the plug-in will send the id of the P to the server, so you just make sure it has an id from which you can determine the database id of the paragraph (maybe somethink like id="p_27" - in which case you should change "int id" in your action to "string id"). Have a look at the jEditable documentation, particularly the id option.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to provide `controller actions` and corresponding `Views` for `Edit` operation. You can then restrict this action /operation only to Admin by using [**Security**](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-17-cs.aspx) infrastructure provided by Asp.Net.

something similar

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var dataToEdit = (from c in _entities.ContactSet
                           where c.Id == id
                           select c).FirstOrDefault();

    return View(contactToEdit);
}
```

Have a look at this tutorial, will give an idea of how it works

- [**Contact Management ASP.NET MVC
  Application**](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-26-cs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Check out my codeplex project @ http://editregion.codeplex.com/.  It pretty much does what you describe and stores the content in xml files in the app_data folder and may be sufficient for your purposes.